# Can't fetch latest commits from GitHub with egit on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I successfully commit some changes from one PC and push to GitHub. Then, I fetch from upstream with `egit` in Eclipse on the other PC, but nothing can be fetched. I can see the changes in synchronize view[team-advanced-synchronize-fetch_head]. What's going wrong here?

You can see [my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/fxbird/Data-Scrapping-Lib), as well as [the most recent commit](https://github.com/fxbird/Data-Scrapping-Lib/commit/94fbcb9439ac69b2d5281552d6f4124948142181).

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of the difference between fetch and pull? When you fetch, then your local PC only "knows" about the remote changes, but does not yet merge them into your local code. So you either want to fetch and afterwards merge, or you just want to pull (which does fetch and merge together).

Comment: Pull also didn't make any difference in my enviroment. And I used fetch to check out the latest code before, and it worked fine , just not always fine.